# Gitlab CI won't serve Angular app to staging environment

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to set up a pipeline that does the following:

Commit new Angular code
Build live review app for testing
Manual push to production
I have been able to successfully build the app within the pipeline using a docker file and have the proper nginx configuration for routing it to the staging environment. Once the job passes, the staging environment is updateed but there is nothing running and the link provided gives a “default backend - 404” error message. I would appreciate any guidance on how to get this link to properly serve the live angular app. Thanks in advance.

Dockerfile:

```
  # Stage 0, "build-stage", based on Node.js, to build and compile the frontend
  FROM tiangolo/node-frontend:10 as build-stage

  WORKDIR /app

  COPY package*.json /app/

  RUN npm install

  COPY ./ /app/

  ARG configuration=production

  RUN cd /app && npm run build --prod --configuration $configuration


  # Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
  FROM nginx:alpine

  RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

  COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

  COPY /nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  RUN cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Gitlab-ci.yml Deploy

```
deploy_stage:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:stable-git
  services:
    - docker:stable-dind
  script:
    - docker build -t my-angular-project:prod .
    - docker run -d -p 80:80 my-angular-project:prod
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://$CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG-staging.$AUTO_DEVOPS_DOMAIN
  only:
    refs:
      - master
    kubernetes: active
    variables:
      - $STAGING_ENABLED
```

NGINX config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The staging environment is not accessible because you do not deploy your app in this job. As I see you're using the kubernetes cluster. After building docker image you should push it e.g to the project's gitlab registry and then passing it to the deployment definition (or helm chart) for kubernetes and applying it. Then you would have deployed it to the cluster. Ah and too make the endpoint accessible remember to configure cluster's ingress too redirect requests to the right deployment based on sub-domain.